# Jasper Reports - Custom Barcode Generation

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, barcode

Libraries/Tools used: 
1) Jasper Reports
2) iReport
3) Java

I've already generated some standard barcodes for my reports, but this time, I'm trying to generate a custom barcode, for which I've a font file custom-barcode.ttf. As of now, iReport supports 2 barcode libraries - Barcode4j and Barbecue, which don't support the custom barcode that I need. Any ideas to get started, without much overhead of using some new library (I'm using Barcode4j already)?

BTW, I'm aware that a similar question ([custom barcode font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303510/custom-barcode-font)) exists on this site already.

Comment: If you have custom-barcode.ttf, then is it as simple as putting a text element in the report and using this font?

Comment: mdahlman, I looked into this before by installing the font through iReport designer and pulling a text field onto the report and setting the pdfEmbedded property. My try wasn't complete, but somehow that didn't make sense. Anyways, I'll try this again and get back to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tried @mdahlman's answer and it worked. I generated the value `"CODE123"` using a [barcode39 font](http://www.barcodesinc.com/free-barcode-font/) (free) and Jaspersoft Barbecue. [image: Sample Barcode]

Setting the size is not very easy using the font but the result is the same. I verified the barcode using Barcode Scanner on my Android phone (can see it's visually similar too). The reason this worked for me, probably same reason @bchetty's test didn't work, is because [Barcode39](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39) doesn't have a check-digit. It is a 1-to-1 translation except with a leading and trailing asterisk (*) appended to the data. If you want to use a ttf to generate a barcode type that has a check-digit you'll need a function (external jar like you mentioned) to encode it. Barcode39 doesn't need a function since it's just `"*" + V${data} + "*"`.

Comment: I didn't verify your answer, but I know what you said is correct. So, selecting your answer as answer. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have custom-barcode.ttf, it really can be treated as text. So your steps are like this:

1. Create a font extension in iReport for custom-barcode.ttf.
2. Create a Text Field in the report with a relevant expression.
3. Set the font for the Text Field to "custom-barcode" (or whatever you call your font extension). Play with the font size to get the desired output.

Using a custom font for a barcode could be considered a bit of a hack. But what it lacks in flexibility it makes up for in simplicity.

Comment: mdahlman, my customer's requirements changed. So, I couldn't get to work on this. So, sorry for the late response. Anyways, I wanted an answer for this and hence the bounty. I just tried this and it worked. So, thank you very much for the answer. I tried it before I put a bounty on this question too, but somehow I couldn't see the barcode in the preview, coz I'd HTML preview. I changed it to PDF preview and it worked. :)

Comment: mdahlman, I got an opportunity to test it with a barcode scanner and the barcode generated by using the above logic, is unintelligible. So, this is not the answer. I've always wondered about this, as if it was that easy to generate a barcode, why would someone use loads of jars files as dependencies, to generate barcodes? Anyways, the above logic generates some kind of barcode (because of the font), but it is not really readable by the machine.

Comment: Using a font to generate barcodes is indeed a hack (as I mentioned originally). What if you make the text bold or italic? This has no meaning for barcodes. What if the HTML client doesn't have this font (which will be true almost always)? Then you cannot use this in HTML. A much cleaner solution is to generate an image. That's why barcode4j and barbecue and ZXing do that. But that's a different level of work (Java coding). Given the starting point that you have a .ttf which claims to generate barcodes... then you need to apply it to a text field.